# The number of distinct ways to form a particular vector

Tags: combinatorics

Let $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4$ be natural numbers $\geq 2$ such that $m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4=2q$ for some natural $q$ and 
$m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4\leq q$. In how many ways can one form a vector $(x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_q,y_q)$ such that:

1. $x_i\neq y_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots, q$,
2. $x_i,y_i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ for all $i=1,\ldots, q$,
3. 1 appears $m_1$ times, 2 appears $m_2$ times, 3 appears $m_3$ times, 4 appears $m_4$ times.

Any hints or references are very welcome.

**EDIT:** The objective is to find an explicit expression of this number as a function of the $m_i,\ i=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: Would an answer in terms of some symmetric functions f(x) and f(y) be useful to you? Or are you looking for a strictly combinatorial counting technique?

Comment: At least I would like to know the (explicit) answer. The technique to use in a situation like this would also be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take the case of q=5 as an example;
Generally, any solution like  {x={3,1,3,1,1},y={4,2,1,4,2}} can be written in the form x_i < y_i by sorting the x_i y_i pairs *and* sorting the x_i ascendingly; 
result is in this case {x={1,1,1,1,3},y={2,2,3,4,4}}.
Given such a sorted 'partial' solution, the problem then reduces to reconstructing all alowable configurations from that. I leave this as (ahum) an exercise to the reader. Handwavingly so.

First remark that the allowable m_i are generated by the partitions of 2*q into 4 parts each in [2, ..,q] , in Mathematica 9.0 :
q = 5; 2+(PadRight[#,4] & /@ IntegerPartitions[2*q-8,4,Range[q-2]])
this gives two allowed sets of m_i: {{4, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 2}}

As a function of q=1 .. 24, there are a[q] such partitions:
{0,0,0,1,2,5,8,13,19,27,36,48,61,77,95,116,139,166,195,228,264,304,347,395}

Now, it turns out all partial solutions are Semi-Standard Young Tableaux of shape {q,q}, so 2 rows of q integers each, weakly sorted within rows and strictly within columns.
If I generate all SSYT of shape {5,5} with contents {4,2,2,2} then I get two tableaux: {{1,1,1,1,3},{2,2,3,4,4}} and {{1,1,1,1,2},{2,3,3,4,4}};
The other allowed set of m_i is {3,3,2,2}, and that generates 3 partial solutions:
{{1,1,1,3,3}, {2,2,2,4,4}}, {{1,1,1,2,3}, {2,2,3,4,4}} and {{1,1,1,2,2}, {2,3,3,4,4}}.

Does the above satisfy the "any hints" requirement?

For the explicit counts, without the 2^q x_i,y_i switches, I find for q=4 .. 12
36,220,1315,8281,35504,200040,876489,4447069,19690891
using
Table[miset = 
  2 + (PadRight[#1, 4] & ) /@ IntegerPartitions[2*q - 8, 4, Range[q - 2]]; 
    Tr[Function[z, 
      Tr[(Multinomial @@ Length /@ Split[Transpose[#1]] & ) /@ 
              Select[SSYT[{q, q}, 4], allcontents[#1] === z & ]]] /@ 
   miset], 
   {q, 3, 12}]

EDIT 07/03/2014 10:41 CET:
on reflection, I see 2 errors in the above :
firstly, the assignment of the m_i to the integers (1 .. 4) implies a free choice, so we get an extra factor equal to the multinomial of the runs in the m_i sets;
secondly, and harder to correct, the column-strict row-weakly sorted arrangements generated by the SSYT undercount the allowable arragements. After sorting within the columns (introducing a factor 2^q) we can sort the 2-rowed table by *the first row* (the x_i), but that does not guarantee the second row will be weakly increasing: we miss the configuration ..., x_i=1, y_i=4, x_(i+1)=2, y_(i+1)=3, ...
I admit being unable to rectify this on the fly.  Sorry.

Comment: @Wouter_M. : Sorry, I see now that I was not very clear with the problem. Would you please see the edited question?

Comment: Well, for q=4, there is only one set of m_i : {2,2,2,2};  
This set allows for 3 partial solutions:
{{1,1,3,3},{2,2,4,4}}, {{1,1,2,3},{2,3,4,4}} and {{1,1,2,2},{3,3,4,4}}  
These partial solutions can be permuted to respectively 6, 24 and 6 column strict solutions (with xi < yi). Times 2^4=16 versions of each.
Your ammended request asks for an explicit expression as function of the mi-set. This cannot be done because the partial solutions (the SSYT) can have repeated columns as in the example above.

Comment: There exists a nice solution for the number of SSYT of shape lambda={q,q} with content mu={m1,m2,m3,m4} : Kostka matrix( row mu, column lambda). But your requirement of counting final solutions (i.o. partial ones) spoils this.